# DateTime returning min value when executed in separate .cs file

Tags: c#, datetime

So Im writing a user log system and unfortunately when I try to save the date in a user, it doesn't work, but when i call it manually, it works perfectly.

```
User.cs

    class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            creationDate = DateTime.Now;
                    
        }
        public DateTime CreationDate{get;set;}
        private DateTime creationDate = new DateTime();
    }
Program.cs

    User user = new User();
    Console.Write(user.CreationDate); //Output: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now); // Output: 7/6/2021 10:55:26 AM (e.g. the correct time)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `CreationDate`, the property, has *nothing* to connect it to `creationDate`, the field.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb lmao. Thanks for the quick answer, Damien!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property and your field are entirely unrelated. Nothing is *using* the field - but that's what you're setting in the constructor.

The simplest option would be to just get rid of the field entirely, and use the property everywhere:

```cs
class User
{
    public User()
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;                
    }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

(As a side note, `DateTime.Now` isn't generally as good for a timestamp-like value as `DateTime.UtcNow`, unless you're *really* only ever interested in the system local time zone, and you don't mind if values go backwards or skip around daylight saving time changes.)